# Finding duration between two dates in python using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I do have a 'input.csv' file with two columns i.e. 'start_date' and 'end_date'. I have to add column of the duration between the dates without using loops. I have tried the following code.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

data = pd.read_csv('data/input.csv')

# converting each data field into date format
data['start_date'] = map(lambda t:datetime.strptime(t,'%Y%M%d'), data.start_date.values)
data['end_date'] = map(lambda t:datetime.strptime(t,'%Y%M%d'), data.end_date.values)

# evaluating the duration
data['duration'] = data.end_date.values - data.start_date.values
```

It shows the following error

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'map' and 'map'
```

Initially the format of date is YYYYMMDD in string format like 20170516 20180931 etc.
I tried a few alternative but didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data['end_date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['end_date'], format='%Y%m%d')
data['start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['start_date'], format='%Y%m%d')
data["duration"] = data['end_date'] - data['start_date']
```

This worked. I used references from other comments.

Answer (score 1):

I was doing this yesterday! Cheers.

```
data['end_date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['end_date'])
data['start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['start_date'])
data["duration"] = data['end_date'] - data['start_date']
```

[to_datetime](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) is fairly robust and can deduce formats.

Comment: That converted the date to 1970-01-01 00:00:00.020040812 for 12/08/2004 i.e. 20140812 which I mentioned as the given format of date.

Comment: using format('date_format') argument is to_datetime function worked

Answer (score 0):

Even simpler, you could do:
`data["duration"] = data['end_date'] - data['start_date']`
The type of the new "duration" column would be Timedelta.  To get number of days:
`data["duration"][0].days`
returns number of days, type `int`